# Connect Callable to Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

### The problem

I cannot bind a callable class to another class (say, `MyClass`) the same way that one could bind a function to `MyClass`. Does anyone know how to manually bind callables to classes, such that instances of `MyClass` automatically pass `self` as the first argument to the callable?

### The Details

I have a function decorator `@logger` which converts the function into a class and stores metadata about its usage (i.e. `function` -> `LoggedFunction`). This works well with functions, and allows some powerful debugging. However, when decorating methods of a class in the same way, since the `LoggedFunction` is a class posing as a function it does not automatically become bound the way a function would.

### The Code

```py
In [1]: # func is a callable that we want to use as a method in a class
    ... def func(*args, **kwargs):
    ...     print(args, kwargs)
    ... 
    ... # Func instances are callables that we want to act the same as `func`
    ... class Func():
    ...     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...         print(args, kwargs)
    ... 
    ... # adding both to MyClass
    ... class MyClass():
    ...     func = func
    ...     Func = Func()
    ... 
    ... myinstance = MyClass()

In [2]: func('arg', kwarg='kwarg')
    ... # function prints all of its inputs
Out[2]: ('arg',) {'kwarg': 'kwarg'}

In [3]: Func('arg', kwarg='kwarg')
    ... # callable class mirrors the performance of the function `func`...
Out[3]: ('arg',) {'kwarg': 'kwarg'}

In [4]: myinstance.func('arg', kwarg='kwarg')
    ... # function is bound to the class, and gets passed `self`
Out[5]: (<__main__.MyClass object at 0x0000012B1F991588>, 'arg') {'kwarg': 'kwarg'}

In [5]: myinstance.Func('arg', kwarg='kwarg')
    ... # callable did not get bound to the class, and does not get passed `self`
Out[5]: ('arg',) {'kwarg': 'kwarg'}
```

Comment: You'll need to use the descriptor protocol: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. If you post as an answer I can give you credit